# Add static column

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I would like to add static content for one of my columns - for all rows.
For ex.: the last column should contain in all its rows a constant string value.

Question: How can I do this or implement this? (sorry I'm a noob in Xamarin, just learning)

```html
    <StackLayout>
        <SearchBar x:Name="filterText" HeightRequest="40"
           Placeholder=" Globális Keresés ... " TextChanged="FilterText_TextChanged"
            Grid.Row="0" />
        <sfgrid:SfDataGrid x:Name = "dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            AllowSorting="True" SelectionMode="Single" ColumnSizer="Star" AllowDraggingColumn="True"
             AllowResizingColumn="True" ItemsSource="{Binding PagedSource, Source={x:Reference dataPager}}" AllowMultiSorting="True"
             GridStyle="{StaticResource dark}" GroupingMode = "Multiple" PullToRefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" AllowPullToRefresh="True"
              SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged">
            <sfgrid:SfDataGrid.Columns x:TypeArguments="syncfusion:Columns">
                <sfgrid:GridTextColumn HeaderText="Halott Család Neve" 
                                   MappingName="Halott_családneve" />
                <sfgrid:GridTextColumn HeaderText="Lánykori Neve"
                                   MappingName="Halott_lánykori_neve" />
                <sfgrid:GridTextColumn HeaderText="Halott Kereszt Neve"
                                   MappingName="Halott_keresztneve" />
                <sfgrid:GridTextColumn HeaderText="Halott Adatai"
                                   MappingName="Halott_adatai" />
                <!--<sfgrid:GridTextColumn HeaderText="További adatok"
                                  MappingName ="'Test'" />-->
            </sfgrid:SfDataGrid.Columns>
        </sfgrid:SfDataGrid>
        <StackLayout >
            <!--16/35 HeightRequest="120" Margin="20,20,20,20" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"-->
            <sfpager:SfDataPager x:Name ="dataPager" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="9,9,9,9"
                               Grid.Row="0"           
                               PageSize="10"
                               PageIndexChanged="DataPager_PageIndexChanged"
                               NumericButtonCount="1"
                               Source="{Binding Items}">
            </sfpager:SfDataPager>
         </StackLayout>
         <Label x:Name="totalText" LineHeight="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" XAlign="Start" YAlign="Center"/>
     </StackLayout>
```

Comment: "Represents the column which is used to display additional information in columns which are not bound with data object." - https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/xamarin/Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.GridUnboundColumn.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of Jason I managed to make it work using this:

```html
                <sfgrid:GridUnboundColumn Expression="➡️"
                         LoadUIView="True" HeaderText="..."
                         HeaderTextAlignment="Start" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                         Width="45" CellTextSize="30"
                         TextAlignment="Center"/>
```